# Create a Javascript Callback function?

Tags: javascript

i was wondering how to implement a callback into this piece of code

```
MyClass.myMethod("sth.", myCallback);
function myCallback() { // do sth };
```

---

```
var MyClass = {

myMethod : function(params, callback) {

    // do some stuff

    FB.method: 'sth.',
       'perms': 'sth.'
       'display': 'iframe'
      },
      function(response) {

            if (response.perms != null) {
                // How to pass response to callback ?
            } else {
                // How to pass response to callback ?
            }
      });
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is call the callback function the normal way. In this case you would just do `callback(response)`.

```
var MyClass = {

myMethod : function(params, callback) {

// do some stuff

FB.method: { 'sth.',
   'perms': 'sth.'
   'display': 'iframe'
  },
  function(response) {

        if (response.perms != null) {
            // How to pass response to callback ?
            // Easy as:
            callback(response);
        } else {
            // How to pass response to callback ?
            // Again:
            callback(response);
        }
  });
}

}
```

Answer (score 13):

three ways to achieve "// How to pass response to callback ?" :

1. `callback(response, otherArg1, otherArg2);`
2. `callback.call(this, response, otherArg1, otherArg2);`
3. `callback.apply(this, [response, otherArg1, otherArg2]);`

1 is the simplest, 2 is in case you want to control the '`this`' variable's value inside your callbackfunction, and 3 is similar to 2, but you can pass a variable number of arguments to `callback`.

here is a decent reference: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: Very complete answer... nice!

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke the passed in function.

```
callback(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply call `callback(response.perms)` there. You could also register it as a

**member of your class:**

```
  MyClass.cb = callback;
```

and later call it:

```
 MyClass.cb(response.perms)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close... just use the callback.  In this instance, you can form a closure.

```
var MyClass = {

myMethod : function(params, callback) {

    // do some stuff

    FB.method: 'sth.',
       'perms': 'sth.'
       'display': 'iframe'
      },
      function(response) {

            if (response.perms != null) {
                callback(response);
            } else {
                // response is null, but you can pass it the same as you did above - if you want to.  Probably better to have a generic failure handler
                ajaxFailHandler();
            }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
callback.call(null, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass.myMethod("sth.", myCallback);
var myCallback = function myCallback() { // do sth }
```

---

```
var MyClass = {

myMethod : function(params, callback) {

    // do some stuff

    FB.method: 'sth.',
       'perms': 'sth.'
       'display': 'iframe'
      },
      function(response) {

            if (response.perms != null) {
                callback();
            } else {
                callback();
            }
      });
}

}
```

Comment: Not sure why you posted this... but you're not passing the `response` variable to your callback.  `callback(response);` will do the trick - as indicated in the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

You've got a reference to a function now. Just invoke it:

```
callback(response.perms);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var callback = function() {

};
```

Thats it :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `callback(response)`?

Comment: This does not seem to have any bearing on the question.

Comment: Well, I could just call `callback()` in the dephest method.

Comment: @fabian: Exactly, as the other 6 posters suggested :)

Comment: fabian, I advise that you disregard this answer. This is not an answer to your question at all - this is completely unrelated.